# Spatie Laravel Translation Loader with Inertia JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, translation, inertiajs

Because I need to store translation text in the database so that users can update it, I'm using the spatie/laravel-translation-loader package. In my application, I'm combining Inertia JS and Vue 2. I'm looking for advice on how to effectively pass translation data to the Vue component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following strategy:

I've shared the following translation data:

```php
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
...
public function share(Request $request)
{
...

'trans' => [
        'common' =>   LanguageLine::getTranslationsForGroup(app()->currentLocale(),'common')
    ],
...
}
...
```

Created trans() function and global mixin

```js
export default function(group, key) {
    let value = _.get(this.$page.props.trans[group], key);
    if (value) {
        return value;
    } else {
       return key;
    }
}
```

```js
import trans from '@/utils/trans';
Vue.prototype.$trans = trans;
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        trans: trans
    },
});
```

used trans() in vue component as:

```
<template>

...
 <h1> trans('common', 'dashboard') </h1>
...
</template>
```